# Ubuntu 22.04 Nvidia driver 520 error trying to sleep

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

The error message is as follows:

```
pci_pm_suspend(): nv_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x30 [nvidia] returns -5
dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x190 returns -5
nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -5
```

I have tried the steps outlined here
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/laptop-unable-to-suspend/16290/14
but this seems to be a solution for fedora and my system does not seem to contain nvidia-suspend.service in that location

I also completely ripped my computer of my nvidia driver and reinstalled driver from scratch to no success

Does anyone have advice on getting Nvidia to suspend properly?

Comment: How exactly are you installing the Nvidia driver? And for which Nvidia card?

Comment: You can create the file also under /etc/modprobe.d/  Control `m̀odinfo nvidia | fgrep parm`  if this key is available in ubuntu.